# Typeorm : Using multiple databases in a single connection Postgresql - nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm following this documentation and it's impossible to communicate with 2 databases in a single connection :

https://typeorm.io/#/multiple-connections/using-multiple-databases-in-a-single-connection

I succeed with 2 different connections, but I need to do it in one. At the end of the chapter it's written :

> This feature is supported only in mysql and mssql databases.

I'm using Postgresql. Is it the problem?

If anyone has an explanation, a full example or a repository it would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

If it could help anyone, this is the solution.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER <connection_name>
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host <host>, dbname <dbname>, port <port>);

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR <user>
SERVER <connection_name>
OPTIONS (user <user>, password <password>);

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA <schema_name>
LIMIT TO (<table_name>)
FROM SERVER <connection_name> INTO <schema_name>;
```

Source : https://www.akinjide.me/2017/cross-database-querying-in-postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

The TypeOrmModule Provides Multiple database connection handling by adding multiple modules with different connection names.

NOTE: The name property is important

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      name: 'Connection1', // this is what will be used
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'database1',
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      name: 'Connection2',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'database2',
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now in your UserModule

```js
 // same entity can be used on different connections or if you want you can use different
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity], 'Connection1'),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity], 'Connection2'),
  ],
  providers: [UserService]
})
```

In User Service

```js
@Injectable()
class UserService {
  constructor (
@InjectRepository(UserEntity, 'Connection1') private userCon1Repo: Repository<UserEntity>,
@InjectRepository(UserEntity, 'Connection2') private userCon2Repo: Repository<UserEntity>,
}
```

The main takeaway is that if you want to maintain multiple connections you have to name the connection when configuring your connection in the forRoot or forRootAsyn and when injecting the entity you need to provide the connection name in the second parameter.

I think the name when not provided is **default**.

***The same is for Sequelize.***